# Since it's not a maven project how to build https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Since it's not a maven project, how to build https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Maven repository here:

https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.snowflake%22

There is also full documentation support here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-install.html

Comment: Hey mike, I want to build(compile locally), would like to debug spark execution, can you help on that how can acheive with spark-snowflake github project?

Comment: SBT tool can be used to build scala projects.
https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html